# Iterating through processes in Python leads to `[Errno 3] assume no such process`

Tags: python, psutil

In Python 3.9.15, if I run `psutil.process_iter()` and then iterate through the processes I get an error. Here's some simple code that does it:

```
import psutil
print(psutil.__version__)  # 5.9.0

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        proc.name()
    except psutil.ZombieProcess:
        # Just skip any ZombieProcesses we come across
        pass
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        # This is the one error I'm concerned about
        print(proc)  # Reports status='terminated'
        raise
```

The result is `ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] assume no such process (originated from sysctl(KERN_PROCARGS2) -> EINVAL)`. I'm running this on an up-to-date OS X (Monterey 12.5.1). I can simply swallow the error like I do with `ZombieProcess`, but I'd like to understand what is going on first and then if there is a more "correct" workaround.

Comment: Since you're on Python 3.8.5, I assume your psutil might be older too. There was this bug fixed a while back: `1766, [macOS]: NoSuchProcess may be raised instead of ZombieProcess.` in psutil 5.7.1. You might try upgrading and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks @sj95126. I have psutil 5.9.0. Anaconda doesn't want to give me 5.9.1, even if I update Anaconda itself, but at any rate I am past 5.7.1. As a result of my upgrading I am on Python 3.8.13 now, however.

Comment: Copying up here what @Amruta noted in a comment below: this seems to be an error with Mac permissioning. More [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2189)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend debugging a bit further to see if this is caused by a specific proc

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
try:
    proc.name()
except psutil.ZombieProcess:
    print(proc)
    pass
```

Proc usually prints out `status`

I'm not sure if you're sure you have a zombie process or if you're checking for one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Amruta I was catching `ZombieProcess` so I could ignore it--thus the `pass` statement. I've updated the code to make it clearer that `NoSuchProcess` is the exception I'm concerned about.

Comment: Please read [answer]. If the question is unclear, then do not attempt an answer in the answer section. At 50 reputation you can use the comment section to explain specific problems or give feedback; at 15 reputation you can flag questions to bring attention to them; at 3000 reputation you can cast votes to close questions, which will block answers until the problem is resolved.

Comment: @kuzzooroo Looks like a problem with Mac and it's permissions. There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2189) about that. I don't think there's anything else to do at the moment. I have been logging it as a warning

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't have 50 reps :')